# Uwp image scaling

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to scale images in gridview items using RenderTransform. Scaling 
performed successfully but scaled image is in behind the gridview items. how to bring it to front.

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
 <Storyboard  >
  <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderRectangle" 
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" />
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  
      Storyboard.TargetName="contentborderscale" 
      Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" >
       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2" />
   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="contentborderscale" 
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0" Value="2"  />
   </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
 </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you want to scale the Container of the GridViewItem.

I check my answer to [GridView selectedItem Popup
(Method 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681242/uwp-gridview-selecteditem-popup/44707177#44707177)

> ### Method 2: On Pointer Hover
>
> **XAML Part**
>
> ```
> <GridView Height="200">
>     <GridView.ItemTemplate>
>         <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ItemSource">
>             <Grid Width="100" Height="100" PointerEntered="GridView_PointerEntered" PointerExited="GridView_PointerExited">
>                 <!-- Content -->
>             </Grid>
>         </DataTemplate>
>     </GridView.ItemTemplate>
>     <GridView.ItemsPanel>
>         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
>             <ItemsWrapGrid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
>         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
>     </GridView.ItemsPanel>
> </GridView>
> ```
>
> **C# Part**
>
> ```
> FrameworkElement lastPopUpElement = null;
> private void GridView_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     lastPopUpElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as FrameworkElement) as FrameworkElement) as FrameworkElement;
>     Canvas.SetZIndex(lastPopUpElement, 1);
>     lastPopUpElement.Scale(scaleX: 1.5f, scaleY: 1.5f, centerX: 50, centerY: 50, easingType: EasingType.Sine).Start();
> }
>
> private void GridView_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     if (lastPopUpElement != null)
>     {
>         Canvas.SetZIndex(lastPopUpElement, 0);
>         lastPopUpElement.Scale(centerX: 50, centerY: 50, easingType: EasingType.Sine).Start();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> [image]